# What are blazor RootComponents?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

The blazor template has this:

```cs
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
```

I know what `App` and `HeadOutlet` are (they are covered in the docs).

What are `RootComponents` generally?

Can I add my own components too? (What sort of components might those be?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are RootComponents generally?

The Renderer needs a starting node for a RenderTree.  That's the root component.  A WASM application can have one or more.  It's probably easier to demonstrate that describe.

Create a project from the WebAssembly template.

Here's a modified index.html.  Notice the extra html `Div` and `Span` elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorApp1</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="counter"></div>

    <span id="useless"></span>

    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Run that and nothing is different.

Now modify `Program` to tell the Application to map `Counter` to the html element with the appropriate id:

```cs
using BlazorApp1;
using BlazorApp1.Pages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.RootComponents.Add<Counter>("#counter");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

You now have three RenderTree's.

> Can I add my own components too? (What sort of components might those be?)

Any class that implements `IComponent` can be a root component.

Here's a demo:

```cs
public class TotallyUselessComponent : IComponent
{
    private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
    public void Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
        => _renderHandle = renderHandle;

    public Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        _renderHandle.Render((builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddMarkupContent(0, $"<div class='alert alert-danger m-3'>I'm here but I'm totally Useless.</div>");
            }
        );

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And Update `Program`

```cs
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.RootComponents.Add<Counter>("#counter");
builder.RootComponents.Add<TotallyUselessComponent>("#useless");
```

Screen shot of what you get.

[image]

Comment: Thanks MrC. I can't imagine when I'd ever add another root component, but maybe my imagination is poor. Can you imagine a situation in which one would want multiple roots?

Comment: Think of an hydrid/mongrel application.  You want to mix React, ...., and Blazor for some reason.  Also you want to migrate from an Asp.net or Razor Server Side application in steps.  Not for me, but....   I see you make 10K points. :-).

Comment: Multi roots: yes I guess that makes sense, more flexibility. Points: yeah thanks you beat me to it, but I got there finally! :-)